# jQuery slideToggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, slidetoggle

My javascript:

```
$("#preview-click").click( function() {
    $("#preview").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $("#preview-pdf").html('<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/pdf/3.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<a id="preview-click" style="cursor: pointer;">preview</a>
<div id="preview" class="generic-block-70" style="display: none">
    <div id="preview-pdf" class="generic-content-70">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the div to slide down then change the content of it. If the `iframe` is already in the div and I simply slideToggle, the frame doesn't render correctly -- that's why I need to generate the content only after the div has been made visible.

The solution above simply isn't working at all. Nothing happens when I click the link.

I should also note that I have more than one `$(document).ready()`

Comment: You need to `return FALSE;` in order to prevent the default behavior of the link.

Comment: Works when I put it into jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CyCC3/

Comment: @DaveKiss, `return false;` where? In the `<a>` tag?

Comment: @DominicGreen, that's so weird ... it doesn't work at all for me. How could that be?

Comment: is your code in document ready the js fiddle does this automatically, see my answer below

Comment: Do you have the jQuery libraries loaded to your page?

Comment: @MaxMackie check updated answer below.

Comment: @Rondel, yup jQuery is loaded

Comment: @MaxMackie Are you loading any other external Javascript libraries that may conflict with jQuery?

Comment: @Rondel, right now only jQuery (`jquery-1.7.1.min.js`) and StackExchange's PageDown (http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on my js fiddle here are you using document ready http://jsfiddle.net/CyCC3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#preview-click").click( function() {
    $("#preview").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $("#preview-pdf").html('<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/pdf/3.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    });
}); 

});
```

Comment: Yeah I have 2 `document.ready`'s on that page. I've read that having more than one is alright, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#preview-click").click( function() {
    $("#preview").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $("#preview-pdf").html('<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/pdf/3.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: This isnt the solution to his issue unfortunately it works without the return false such as http://jsfiddle.net/CyCC3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#preview-click").click( function() {
    $("#preview").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $("#preview-pdf").html('<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/pdf/3.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    });
    return FALSE;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case,Slidetoggle works within my iframe partly but it left white space and I still finding the answer how to fix that.

My JS

```
    $(document.myform).ready(function() {
       $('div.demo:eq(0)> div#headerview').click(function() {
       $(this).next().slideToggle('20');
    });
  });
```

My Html

```
<div class="demo">
<div id="headerview" style="cursor:pointer;">SlideStarts</div>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I try to change iframe height when slide up and down but is still looks stupid.